# How to take user input before Deleting the record in ASP.NET c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to take a user input before deleting record if the input match with the record name then record will be deleted successfully.

This is JS Function.

```
  var object = { status: false, ele: null };

    function ConfirmDelete(ev) {
        if (object.status) { return true; };
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this Record!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: true
        },
            function () {
                object.status = true;
                object.ele = ev;
                object.ele.click();
            });
        return false;
    };
```

This is the C# code.
Code is working fine but I want to take user input before user delete the record.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int id;

            id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@".....");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From [CTL].[EntityMaster] where EntityNumber = " + id);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        int row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (row > 0)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "K", "swal('Deleted!','Record Deleted with Entity number =" + id + "','success')", true);
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"....");
            con1.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select * From [CTL].[EntityMaster]");
            cmd1.Connection = con1;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd1.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    
                    
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        Button6.Visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: use `window.confirm` instead of going this road. if use clicks `yes` then the form will be submit it (doPostBack)` otherwise, it will not take any action.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages. Please don't tag one when you mean the other.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like some of those sweet alert options are older, or outdated.

So, our grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" width="40%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"
                    OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete(this);" >
                </asp:Button>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Our code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

We now have this:

[image]

Note how we using a plain simple button for the GV.

So the delete button code is this:

```
    protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button cmdDel = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cmdDel.NamingContainer;
        int PKID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
            new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = @ID");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKID;
        General.MyRstE(cmdSQL);
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

Ok, so now we only need our script:

This works:

```
<script>
    var ConfirmDeleteOk = false
    function ConfirmDelete(btn) {
        if (ConfirmDeleteOk) {
            ConfirmDeleteOk = false;   // not really required
            return true;
        }
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this Record!",
            type: "warning",
            buttons: ["Cancel", "Yes, delete it!"],
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            closeOnConfirm: true
        })
            .then((mysweetVal) => {
                if (mysweetVal) {
                ConfirmDeleteOk = true;
                $(btn).click();
                }
            })
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

And of course, we NOT going to re-type simple code like a query command and connection stuff over and over, right?

So, I have a global simple static class with the two helper routines used in above. They are:

```
    public static DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

and the execute one "E" for those statements:

```
    public static void MyRstE(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

And often I need parameters for the sql query, so I have this one:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```